# In Overleaf, how to upload and sync a file located in an owncloud/nextcloud account?

Tags: overleaf

In an Overleaf project I want to synchronize a file existing in my Nextcloud/Owncloud account. This is a bibliography file (.bib) generated by Zotero/Better BibTex.

Relevant [instructions are given for other popular services](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_can_I_upload_files_from_Google_Drive%3F) but they do not apply to my case with Nextcloud and the link provided by Nextcloud for this text file (.bib) generates a short html code in Overleaf.

Here the link: `https://nextcloud.univ-lille.fr/index.php/s/oKLBX6C5WGrf47m`

Comment: You must use a URL that points to the raw file, not a landing page. In your case you can use https://nextcloud.univ-lille.fr/index.php/s/oKLBX6C5WGrf47m/download instead.

Comment: As an alternative, you can link directly to Zotero: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_to_link_your_Overleaf_account_to_Mendeley_and_Zotero#How_to_link_Mendeley_or_Zotero

And in the future, maybe also fully sync with Nextcloud: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/526

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on the example given here](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/14593#issuecomment-498606888) I have simply added `/download` at the end of the link provided by Nextcloud, after the id of the file, and it works.

- From `https://nextcloud.univ-lille.fr/index.php/s/oKLBX6C5WGrf47m`
- To -> `https://nextcloud.univ-lille.fr/index.php/s/oKLBX6C5WGrf47m/download`